# Texture Paint is missing in the menu - how do I find it?

Tags: texture-painting, navigation, workspaces

I am following a guide on YouTube where I need to use the texture paint. But it is not appearing in my view/ topmenu. Can you please help me to show it in the menu.

This is my view:
[image]

But this is how it looks in the guides

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UI is significantly altered from the default. I noticed one tab labeled “game logic“ and I’m wondering if this is actually leftover UI from an old 2.79 blend file. However, the tab you need might be still there. Hover the mouse over the tab area, and then scroll. If you still don’t see the tab, click the little plus tab at the very end, and you’ll see what you need in the “general“ section of the appearing menu.

Comment: Great - Thanks! 
I guess that the imported head might have caused the problems.
Can I give you some kind of credit for your good help?

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted (green tick in the top left) if it solved your problem and upvote the answer if you feel like it :)

Comment: I wouldn’t think a model import would’ve caused the trouble, but I’m glad the problem’s fixed .